# swagger-codegen or openapi-generator PHP version

Tags: php, docker, version-control, swagger, openapi-generator

**The actual question:** is it possible to choose the PHP version *(5.6, 7.1, 7.2, ...)* to generate code?

I got a `swagger.json` from https://api.otto.market/docs 
*which should be an `openapi.json` or so, since the file contains `"openapi": "3.0.3",`. Anyway ...*

What i found out so far is that they *(swagger and openapi-generator)* seem to have templates for the code generation.
And those templates are written in the language for the version in use.

F.e. this *([openapitools/openapi-generator-cli](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator#16---docker))*

```
docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/local openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate \
-i /local/path/to/swagger.json \
-g php \
-o /local/path/to/generated/code/
```

creates a `composer.json` with

```
...
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3 || ^8.0",
    ...
},
...
```

---

I now COULD use the templates and change the requirements.
But i think this would not be the target of a code generator.
*Info about templates added to bottom.*

What i guess is that there should be templates written for other PHP version.
But how would i choose them?
Are there any?

---

Swagger: as i read swagger came first, and openapi-generator is a fork.
So i tried swagger:

```
docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/local swaggerapi/swagger-codegen-cli generate \
-i /local/path/to/swagger.json \
-l php \
-o /local/path/to/generated/code/
```

Swagger created code for PHP 5.5 (as of the generated `composer.json`).
But it brings warnings and the generated code looks "broken".
*I actually do not wonder since the file is made for `openapi": "3.0.3`.*

But what i see is: swagger has templates for PHP 5.5.

---

My personal current conclusion:
I can generate code real quick f.e. for an API that i do not really *(have to)* know.
But how does it help me if i cannot change the language version?

F.e. i need an API client in 2 projects.
One is in PHP 7.1 and the other one in 7.3. How do i solve this?

**Anybody had to deal with this? Or any ideas?**

---

---

INFO
**templates**: how to use templates:
Call `docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/local openapitools/openapi-generator-cli author template -g php -o /local/templates/`
to save all templates to path `templates/`.
You then can f.e. copy the `composer.mustache` to f.e. `deploy/templates/` and change it.
On generating code you use `-t /local/deploy/templates` to use **your** changed template.
Example:

```
docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/local openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate \
-i /local/path/to/swagger.json \
-g php \
-o /local/path/to/generated/code/ \
-t /local/deploy/templates
```

Answer (score 1):

[Old versions of OpenAPI Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/releases) (e.g. 3.0.0, 4.0.0) support old PHP versions.

To easily switch between OpenAPI Generator CLI versions, you may want to use the [NPM CLI wrapper for OpenAPI Generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli).

Comment: Tried this today. Its kind of "try until it works". We tried some CLI versions until we got a `composer.json` that required `7.1`. Would have been nice if you could give|select a version of the language you provided (`-g`). I really dont understand why ppl did not started with version control on the generators.